# How to change order of Rails date helper select boxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to change the order of Rails' date helper select boxes.

I just upgraded to Rails 3.2.3 and this no longer works:

```
de:
  formats:
    default: "%d/%m/%Y"
    order: [:day, :month, :year]
```

How can this be done?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Rails 3.2 uses other format for the order: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4b1985578a2b27b170358e82e72e00d23fdaf087/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml

Try something like

```
de:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
    order:
      - :day
      - :month
      - :year
```